# check if object in ManyToMany field django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

here is my models.py:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    body = models.TextField(max_length=10000)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    liked_by = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, related_name='liked_by')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-date']
```

serializers.py:

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializers()
    total_likes = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    total_comments = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('id','body','date','user','total_likes','total_comments')

    def get_total_likes(self, instance):
        return instance.liked_by.count()

    def get_total_comments(self, instance):
        return instance.comment_set.count()
```

Q1: how do i check if a user exists in ManyToManyField of a single post?

Q2: shouldn't i use ManyToManyField in drf? then which would be better?

Answer (score 2):

I don't have enough reps to comment, but if you have a `post` instance and a `user` instance, you could do something like:

```
post.liked_by.filter(id=user.id).exists()
```

Does that help you or are you asking where you should be implementing this? e.g. in your view or serializer etc...

Comment:  where should i implement this?

Comment: It depends I guess. What exactly is it you are trying to do?

Comment: For instance, are you trying to perform some kind of serializer validation, custom permission for a view, simply want to include whether a specific user has liked a post in a view's response...?

Comment: i implement this code ```def get_is_liked(self, inctance):
        return inctance.liked_by.filter(id=inctance.user.id).exists()```. but it shows wrong data, sometime shows "is_liked": true, sometime false

Comment: i implement that on PostSerializer

Comment: thanks. it works. i was wrong. thank you

Comment: I am guessing that the user field in the Post model is the author/owner of a post, right? If that's the case, it seems that what you are checking in your get_is_liked method is always whether the author of the post likes his/her own post. Is that what you are trying to know, or do you want to check more generally for any user? EDIT: OK just seen your last comment, glad to help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225978/discussion-between-asif-biswas-and-muscaria).